# How to replace backslashes with forward slashes in a malformed string with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, backslash

```javascript
// malformed string
var str = "C:\Windows\Fonts";

// C:WindowsFonts
alert(str.replace(/\\/g, "/"));
```

How do I correctly replace `\` with `/` so I can get `C:/Windows/Fonts`?

Comment: BTW you are aware that accessing `C:\` can be done only locally, not via the internet.

Comment: uhmmm....it's just a string example, and I'm not trying to access anywhere on the computer. Can we focus on Javascript?

Comment: Are you sure your string is properly comes from outer script? I did simple php <?php echo "c:\derp\herp" ?>, then got it in client page via ajax (jquery) $.ajax({ url: "temp.php", success: function(data) { alert(data); }}); and alert was proper c:\derp\herp as I expected. JS should handle such string normally.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is special character use escape mark

```
var str = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts";
```

Comment: In javascript, `'` and `"` do the same thing.

Comment: How come `str.replace(/\\/g, "/")` doesn't work? How do I correctly replace `\\` with `/`.

Comment: Replace only replaces 1st occurence. So you need to make sth like this. Or implement loop. 
     str = str.replace("\\", "/").replace("\\", "/");

Comment: @Robert ??? `only replaces 1st occurence` ??? I have the `g` flag, which means search and replace `g`lobally.

Comment: Of course if you add G then it'l replace all. 
str = str.replace("\\g", "/"); solves problem

Comment: @RobertPodwika `str = str.replace("\\g", "/");` your code does not work. you put the flag inside a string, and that will actually search for `\g`, not `\\`.

Comment: I run it with Chrome and it works for me. For cross browser compablity you should use RegExp and it's gonna work.

Comment: I found it on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp that it is possible to include g flag into string

Comment: @RobertPodwika I don't see a `g` inside quotes on that page.

Comment: this is not a global flag issue since OP says that not even first (single) slash is replaced

Comment: Check Technical Details. More examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get it works as well as op. JS treats single slash with trailing character as escape sequence. var st = "a\b"; st.replace(/\\/, "/"); st.replace("\\", "/"); st.replace(/\\/g, "/"); all of this calls returns "a". But st.replace(/\b/g, "/") returns you /a/ (once at zero carret position as word boundary, second time as wrong recognized \b my malformed string). How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more backslash to show the special character.

```
var str = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts";
        alert(str);
```

Whenever you use the special character in JAvascript you need to add one backslash.

Comment: I know that, but the string was not defined manually like in the example, it's retrieved from somewhere else.

Comment: use this `str = str.replace("\\", "/").replace("\\", "/");`

Comment: Not scalable at all. What if string is "c:\path\to\deep\deep\deeeeep\directory"?

Comment: I replied that he can use g flag and I've given a sample in post above.