# Replacing backslashes in Javascript with escaped backslahes

Tags: javascript, extjs

Our application needs to process a file path (ie. snip off the last element) which we get in non escaped form **c:\blah\di\blah**. Unfortunately the backslashes are not escaped, like **c:\\blah\\di\\blah**, which means that javascript does not really recognise the backslahes; calling a function like indexOf(\\) will return -1.

I have seen countless [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874048/how-to-replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-in-a-malformed-string-with-javas) on stackOverflow but I am at a loss on how to proceed.

There is *no way* we can change the data we get because it is from another framework (extJS),

Is there some way of replacing the single backslashes with \\ ? Then we could process it properly.

I tried :

- str.replace(/\/, "\\\\");
- str.replace(/\/g, "\\\\");  mentioned  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace).
- str.replace(String.fromCharCode(92),String.fromCharCode(92,92)); mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479309/javascript-and-backslashes-replace)
- str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
- escape() function mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144090/replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslashes). This gives me c%3A%08lahdi%08lah
- In the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144090/replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslashes) this looked promising: **var justTheName = str.split(String.fromCharCode(92)).pop();** But also does not work for me.

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juzntyb6/) with this code :

```
var str = 'c:\blah\di\blah'

str = str.replace(/\\/, "\\\\");

alert('' + str)
```

Comment: when you do ```console.log(str.split('').map(function(ch){ return ch.charCodeAt(0);}));```, you get ```[ 99, 58, 8, 108, 97, 104, 100, 105, 8, 108 ... ``` which means ```\b``` and ```\d``` give the same value ```8``` , that is your roadblock, not sure how to overcome that, are you reading all of this from a file, if so then there is hope...

Comment: No, unfortunately this is supplied within the Javascript code by the extjs framework

Comment: `var str = 'c:\blah\di\blah'` is already "c:lahdilah". There's no way to replace a backslash that doesn't exist.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when ExtJs gives you a string with backslashes in it, doesn't that mean that the backslashes are already escaped? If so, your test is wrong, and you should work with a correctly escaped test-string.

Comment: Extjs gives me a string "c:\blah\di\blah". Whether or not they are escaped or not is irrelevant. The string is not in a state where I can snip off the last part.

Comment: You need to initialize string as:

var str = 'c:\\blah\\di\\blah'

Comment: My point is: If you have a valid string-var with a value that when logged shows "c:\blah\di\blah" and no other errors given, you don't have to concern yourself with *fixing* that string, because it is already a valid value. You only have to correctly split it in your code, e.g.: `str.split('\\').pop()`. Meaning it's your code where you have to handle the escaping correctly, not with the runtime values.

Comment: so you are saying if I SEE it in the console or debugger with 1 slash it means it really has 2 slashes in it?

Comment: Yes, though it's technically not correct, you can think about it that way. For js a backslash is a backslash. Though for the interpreter, when parsing code, a backslash is the escape-character which needs to be escaped when one wants to use it in literal values. E.g. `var foo = 'C:\\';` same as with `str.split('\\').pop()`. The point is: "there is no double-backslash" (pun intended).

Comment: alright i think I sort of got it - extjs is actually giving me the right values.. (Maybe its just me, but this backslash business confuses the heck out of me.)

Comment: Well, you're not the first, and you'll surely not be the last to stumble upon this topic ;)   If possible, think about answering your question, so that future visitors can profit from it.